# Update table from another table with Case Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case

I want to update column 'statusout' in table 'dailydatawh' from table 'dailydata' in column 'dateattend' when 'statustype'=out

```
UPDATE DAILYDATAWH 
SET STATUSOUT=
(SELECT 
 (case when STATUSTYPE='OUT' then DATEATTEND end)as STATUSOUT
FROM DAILYDATA
GROUP By NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT,DATEATTEND,STATUSTYPE)
WHERE STATUSOUT = NULL
```

[image: TABLE DAILYDATA]

[image: TABLE DAILYDATAWH]

--

> After i try the following answer

```
UPDATE DDW
SET    STATUSOUT = DD.DATEATTEND 
FROM   DAILYDATAWH DDW
       INNER JOIN DAILYDATA DD ON DDW.NIP = DD.NIP
                              AND DDW.NAME = DD.NAME
                              AND DDW.DEPARTMENT = DD.DEPARTMENT
WHERE  DD.STATUSTYPE = 'OUT'
```

This query is work, but when i input new data(NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT,DATEATTEND,STATUSTYPE) in table DAILYDATA, the new value in 'STATUSOUT' (table DAILYDATAWH) still appear previous date

[image: TABLE DAILYDATA]
[image: TABLE DAILYDATAWH]

> This is the current output with query :

```
UPDATE DDW
SET    STATUSOUT = DD.DATEATTEND 
FROM   dailydatawh DDW
       INNER JOIN 
       (
           SELECT NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, DATEATTEND = MAX(DATEATTEND)
           FROM   dailydata 
           WHERE  STATUSTYPE = 'OUT'
           GROUP BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT
       ) DD                    ON DDW.NIP = DD.NIP
                              AND DDW.NAME = DD.NAME
                              AND DDW.DEPARTMENT = DD.DEPARTMENT
```

[image: CURRENT OUTPUT]

> This is the Sample input

[image: EXAMPLE input TABLE]

> This is the sample output

[image: EXAMPLE OUTPUT TABLE]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: sorry, my question is how to update column 'statusout' which contains 'dateattend' from that table when statustype = out. i've been try that query but still can't work

Comment: what is the relationship (column name) of these 2 tables ?

Comment: @Squirrel I haven't made it yet, but i think column 'NIP+NAME' can be relation, because 
cannot be the same with other people

Comment: NULL value should always be compared as 'STATUSOUT is NULL'.

Comment: @satishcse i've been try that but appear error 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

Comment: Yeah, that is just for the info. You can use the answer given by Squirrel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inner join the tables (here i am assuming it is based on the column `NIP` as the actual information is not provided)

```
UPDATE DDW
SET    STATUSOUT = DD.DATEATTEND 
FROM   dailydatawh DDW
       INNER JOIN dailydata DD ON DDW.NIP = DD.NIP
                              AND DDW.NAME = DD.NAME
                              AND DDW.DEPARTMENT = DD.DEPARTMENT
WHERE  DD.STATUSTYPE = 'OUT'
```

UPDATED QUERY.

```
UPDATE DDW
SET    STATUSOUT = DD.DATEATTEND 
FROM   dailydatawh DDW
       INNER JOIN 
       (
           SELECT NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, DATEATTEND = MAX(DATEATTEND)
           FROM   dailydata 
           WHERE  STATUSTYPE = 'OUT'
           GROUP BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT
       ) DD                    ON DDW.NIP = DD.NIP
                              AND DDW.NAME = DD.NAME
                              AND DDW.DEPARTMENT = DD.DEPARTMENT
WHERE DDW.STATUSOUT IS NULL
```

UPDATED QUERY #2.

```
UPDATE DDW
SET    STATUSOUT = DD.DATEATTEND 
FROM   dailydatawh DDW
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           SELECT TOP 1 d.DATEATTEND
           FROM   dailydata d
           WHERE  d.STATUSTYPE = 'OUT'
           AND    d.NIP =  DDW.NIP
           AND    d.NAME = DDW.NAME
           AND    d.DEPARTMENT = DDW.DEPARTMENT
           ORDER BY d.ID DESC
       ) DD
WHERE  DDW.STATUSOUT IS NULL
```

This is the query that combines your insert & update into one single query

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT 
                                          ORDER BY DATEATTEND)
    FROM   DAILYDATA
)
INSERT INTO DAILYDATAWH (NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, STATUSIN, STATUSOUT)
SELECT  NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, STATUSIN = MIN(DATEATTEND), STATUSOUT = MAX(DATEATTEND)
FROM    CTE
GROUP BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, (RN - 1) / 2
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73af11ab7f1ce2e7d37492cad637b3ae)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207578/discussion-on-answer-by-squirrel-update-table-from-another-table-with-case-expre).

Comment: Wanted to do that but doesn't seems to have any option for me.

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't know how to do that